# How do we bold AND italicize text in a comment?

Tags: support, status-norepro, markdown

To bold, you put two asterisks (`**`) around the block, and to italicize, you put an underscore (`_`) around the text. There is a problem (bug?) is if you want to bold *and* underline text.

Common sense would tell you to put *both* asterisks and underlines around the text, but that doesn't produce the right results (at least on the mobile site):

`_**lorem ipsum**_`: ***lorem ipsum*** (bold *only*)

`**_lorem ipsum_**`: ***lorem ipsum*** (bold *only*)

So, is this a bug, or is this [Defective by Design](http://www.defectivebydesign.org/) (tm)

Comment: Seems to be working in your example. What are you seeing if ***lorem ipsum*** is not the right results?

Comment: that's quite a bump, are you now experiencing it on anything ***other than a mobile***?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use three asterisks/underscores:

`___foo___ ***bar***` => ***foo*** ***bar***

Actually, `_` and `*` are identical. Only the amount matters: 1 = italic, 2 = bold, 3 = both

Combining `_` and `**` or vice-versa works, too. At least on the non-mobile site.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: Mediawiki uses a different format. On SE sites we use [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/).

Comment: @ColeJohnson the point is so we can have pedantic discussions of whether _ or * is the proper way to apply markdown

Comment: @ColeJohnson NK's storing their nukes in The Tavern? I always knew that place seemed fishy

Answer (score 2):

You put *three* stars *or* underscores around the word: ***italic and bold***.

In full-blown posts, you can combine them any way you like:

- `_**still bold italic**_`: ***still bold italic***
- `**_still bold italic_**`: ***still bold italic***

However, this does **not** work in *comments*. In comments, you have to use three stars *or* three underscores. You cannot mix the styles. The comments parser is a little pickier.

Comment: Yes! That's what I was getting at! Why is the comments section picky? Why can't the same parser be used?

Comment: @ColeJohnson: Because not all of markdown is supported in comments. They don't support bullet points, no quoting, no syntax highlighting of code either.